# How to create a MySQL stored procedure from Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know that in php you can make a function or procedure in the code itself like this

```
$query = "CREATE FUNCTION Example (x INT)
    RETURNS BOOLEAN
       BEGIN
          
       END";
mysql_query($query);

$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
mysql_query($query);
```

Is it possible to do something similar in Ruby?

At the moment, I need to make some kind of project in ruby, but I don’t know and can’t find whether it’s possible to write exactly this inside the code there. I know that everything there is based on Active Record, but is it possible to write the same code as in PHP? This moment is very important for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can write raw SQL in Rails:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM table";
mysql_query = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
```

Comment: it turns out that I can also write the function or procedure itself, right?

Comment: @kaserr Yes, you can. By the way, You can also try using ActiveRecord::Base.connections.exec_query() as it returns an array of hashes. You can try both and use whatever suits your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on rails has certain syntax for accessing SQL database so you **DONT have to write raw sql**. For example "SELECT * FROM Clients" is sth like that in RoR:

```
clients = Client.all
```

I would suggest taking a look at RoR guide about Active Record.
It is always a good practice to use the syntax of the framework you are working on and not using practices from frameworks you were using in the past.Let me know if you need anything else.